# How do i redirect user if user enter the URL with /index.php to without having /index.php in the url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, joomla2.5

I am facing a little problem with URL's redirection in my site. This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 

# Start –301 redirect for "http://" to "http://www"

Options +FollowSymLinks

rewritecond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]

rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,L]

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /?(.*)/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This works fine.All URL works perfectly without having /index.php in it.

But my problem is when someone put a URL with `index.php` (for ex. `https://example.com/index.php/test` ). So it will also works. That's is a problem, I want that when user put the /index.php with the URL it will redirect to the same page without having `/index.php` in it. Please help me to sort this out.

Comment: Why would an user append `index.php` to the URL? Even if they do, why bother "fixing" it? Usually only hackers desire to malform an URL.

Comment: @TimS. It's creating a problem if someone put a url with /index.php it will mark as duplicate url in google. Please help me if you have any suggesion

Comment: No, it won't mark a duplicate. If you don't put any links in your site containing the `index.php` version, the Google crawler won't index it.

Comment: @TimS. but what if someone try to access the url with index.php?

Comment: Then it would just work as expected, and Google wouldn't even know.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this **above** the rules that you already have:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /?(.*)/index\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [L,R=301]
```

If you try to match against the request URI, it will cause a loop because the rules that you already have routes requests to index.php, rewriting the request URI *to* index.php thus causing it to match when rewrite engine loops.

Comment: This will redirect it to home page. Is it possible to redirect it to the same requested page without /index.php ?

Comment: I have update my question as you said to put your code above my rules .If i put it like that it will redirect me to the home page `http://example.com//` so what is a problem in it. Please suggest me.